# Google iOS SDK fails to archive (use of undeclared identifier errors)

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods, google-signin, google-identity

I have attempted to archive my project for submission to App Store, however, every time I get errors "use of undeclared identifier" for everything related to google iOS SDK. The application itself runs and builds flawlessly with the discussed SDK integrated, the only thing that fails is the archive process. I have tried both cocoa pods and manual method of integration (separately, of course). Furthermore, I used the latest xCode versions (6.4 and 7 beta 4) on two different macs running OS X 10.10.4. This is the [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating?hl=en) I have been using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue has something to do with the configuration of archiving in combination with your **Release** settings. If you change the scheme settings `Command + <` to use the **Debug** configuration for archiving, you may be able to successfully archive your app. This means that somewhere you are probably not matching the **Debug** and **Release** configurations.

See the following screenshot for example project **Build Settings** that are missing the Swift bridging header in release:

[image]

Add `bridge.h` to the release configuration and you will be able to build with the Release schema and you will be able to archive under release configuration.

Comment: I have also succeeded archiving with their sample project. I was even able to archive a newly created swift project (I used the same cocoapods setting `pod 'Google/SignIn'`. I have always used version 2.2.0. Is there any particular place I could check to fix my current project? Or setting up a new one is the only option left?

Comment: Sure, but it`s just ALL of the references to the google sdk.

Comment: Only one (in my bridging header)
`#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>`

Comment: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5io2l6ktrc2r9v0/xcode_issue.zip?dl=0) is my project. I have removed all files except for AppDelegate. I still get errors during the archiving process.

Comment: Just try to `Clean` - `Build` - `Archive`. And you will see all the error I am talking about.

Comment: You can build it in XCode 7 beta4. If you don`t have it installed, I will send you a new link in a second.

Comment: [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28533071/xcode_issue_fixed.zip) you go.