# Use of undeclared type while archiving in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I cannot archive the app because of error:

`Use of undeclared type 'MyCustomType'`

Everything is fine when I compile on the iphone.

**What makes the difference?**

`MyCustomType` is a framework

Comment: If iPhone works but simulator doesn't, the first thing that comes to mind is cleaning derivedData, restarting Xcode, etc.

Comment: It works on both: iphone and simulator. It is built with success. But when I try to archive the app to release to app store, then error arise. Why?

Comment: you have multiple configuration like debug , release   ?

Comment: Yes, I have two: debug and release.

Comment: Oh by archive you mean submit to App Store? Where do you define 'MyCustomType'? It seems like that's where the issue is.

Comment: Inside a framework linked as static library.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Check your build settings under `Swift Compiler – Code Generation` for Release configuration. Or... check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31815902/2857130)

Comment: Are you sure it is under Code Generation? Not `Swift Compiler - General`?

Comment: However, it doesnt change anything. Still the same error. While archiving, it still doesnt see my types..